# HTML form, submitting to JS then to server, data not arriving?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The code is to take information on a taxi booking from the HTML form, screen it, then pass to the PHP server to submit into a MySQL database. Unfortunately the values don't seem to be making it into the database. I'm not overly experienced with AJAX so think this could be the problem. Here is my code:

```html
<form id="booking" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    Customer Name:<span class="red">*</span>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="50"/><br/>

    Contact Phone:<span class="red">*</span>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" maxlength="15"/><br/>

    Unit Number:<span class="red">*</span>
    <input type="text" name="unit" id="unit" maxlength="5"/><br/>

    Street Number:<span class="red">*</span>
    <input type="text" name="stNum" id="stNum"/><br/>

    Street Name:<span class="red">*</span>
    <input type="text" name="stName" id="stName" maxlength="50"/><br/>

    Suburb:<span class="red">*</span>
    <input type="text" name="pickup" id="pickup" maxlength="50"/><br/>

    Destination Suburb:<span class="red">*</span>
    <input type="text" name="destination" id="destination" maxlength="50"/><br/>

    Pickup Time:<span class="red">*</span>
    <input type="text" name="time" id="time" placeholder="HH:MM" maxlength="5"/><br/>

    Pickup Date:<span class="red">*</span>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" maxlength="10"/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Book" class="display-inline" id="submit" onclick="submitBooking()"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>
```

```js
// Ajax passing data.
var xhr = createRequest();

function submitBooking()(dataSource, response, name, phone, unit, stNum, stName, pickup, destination, time, date) {
    if(xhr) {
        var data = document.getElementById(response);
        var requestbody = "name=" + encodeURIComponent(name)
            + "&phone=" + encodeURIComponent(phone)
            + "&unit=" + encodeURIComponent(unit)
            + "&stNum=" + encodeURIComponent(stNum)
            + "&stName=" + encodeURIComponent(stName)
            + "&pickup=" + encodeURIComponent(pickup)
            + "&destination=" + encodeURIComponent(destination)
            + "&time=" + encodeURIComponent(time)
            + "&date=" + encodeURIComponent(date);
        xhr.open("POST", dataSource, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                data.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("booking").reset(); // Reset the form on success.
            }
        }
        xhr.send(requestbody);
    }
} // end function getData
```

```php
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Auckland');
require_once 'connect.php';

$status = "unassigned";
$custName = $_POST["name"];
$custNum = $_POST["phone"];
$unit = (isset($_POST["unit"])) ? $_POST["unit"] : null;
$stNum = $_POST["stNum"];
$stName = $_POST["stName"];
$pickupSuburb = $_POST["pickup"];
$destinationSuburb = $_POST["destination"];
$time = $_POST["time"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
$pickupDateTime = date_format(date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i', ($date . " " . $time)), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
$bookingDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// SQL code.
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO taxibooking(status, custName, custNum, unit, streetNum, streetName, pickupSuburb, destinationSuburb, pickupDateTime, bookingDate) VALUES ('{$status}','{$custName}','{$custNum}','{$unit}','{$stNum}','{$stName}','{$pickupSuburb}','{$destinationSuburb}','{$pickupDateTime}','{$bookingDate}')";

$insertSql = mysqli_query($db, $insertQuery);
$booking = mysqli_insert_id($db);

echo "<p>We have you booked with reference number is $booking. We'll see you at your requested addres at $time on $date.</p>";

mysqli_close($db);
```

Comment: Could you check the network tab of the console to see the state and responseText of the request. That should tell you if the request is working, and if not what the error is.

Comment: I'm also presuming that `validateForm()` calls `getData()`? Otherwise the request won't be made at all.

Comment: What Rory said and where is submitBooking()?

Comment: Read this article and check for inconsistencies with your code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX

Comment: Hi Rory, No it doesn't that could be the problem?

Comment: @Jcode: I guess your best bet is to take a look at the `submitBooking` function (perhaps even the `validateForm` function).  Place debugging breakpoints and step through the code as it executes to see where/how it fails.

Comment: The most obvious error is the definition of `function submitBooking`. You'll have to omit the first pair of parentheses there, so it's `function submitBooking(.....)` rather than `function submitBooking()(....)`

Comment: second: It seems like you never set the parameters for submitBooking ... you are calling it like `onclick="submitBooking()"`

Comment: Sorry thats a typo in the JS file, its not actually like that it just has submitBooking(...), shouldnt onclick assign the values to the Javascript file?